# syntax error at end of input LINE 214: o.MatchAdded DESC ^

Tags: sql

I am trying to join 2 queries in an animal shelter database to match dog profiles with potential adopters. I keep getting an error message (syntax error at end of input LINE 214: o.MatchAdded DESC ^ ) and I don't understand why it is not working when it works everywhere else.

I have singled out each query (dog side, applicant side) and they work. I have used the query to match with only 1 specification and it works.

```
 SELECT a.sheltercode,
       a.animalname,
       a.animalage,
       (
              SELECT sex
              FROM   lksex
              WHERE  id = a.sex) AS sex,
       (
              SELECT size
              FROM   lksize
              WHERE  id = a.size) AS size,
       (
              SELECT basecolour
              FROM   basecolour
              WHERE  id = a.basecolourid) AS color,
       s.speciesname,
       a.breedname,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = a.isgoodwithcats) AS goodwithcats,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = a.isgoodwithdogs) AS goodwithdogs,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = a.isgoodwithchildren) AS goodwithchildren,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = a.ishousetrained) AS housetrained,
       (
              SELECT animaltype
              FROM   animaltype
              WHERE  id = matchanimaltype) AS animaltype,
       (
              SELECT speciesname
              FROM   species
              WHERE  id =matchspecies) AS species,
       (
              SELECT breedname
              FROM   breed
              WHERE  id = matchbreed)AS breed,
       (
              SELECT breedname
              FROM   breed
              WHERE  id = matchbreed2) AS orbreed,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = matchgoodwithcats) AS goodwithcats,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = matchgoodwithdogs) AS goodwithdogs,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = matchgoodwithchildren) AS goodwithchildren,
       (
              SELECT NAME
              FROM   lksynun
              WHERE  id = matchhousetrained) AS housetrained,
       (
                SELECT   o.ownername,
                         o.owneraddress,
                         o.hometelephone,
                         o.worktelephone,
                         o.mobiletelephone,
                         o.matchadded,
                         matchcommentscontain,
                         homecheckareas,
                         additionalflags,
                         (
                                    SELECT     af.value
                                    FROM       additional af
                                    INNER JOIN additionalfield aff
                                    ON         aff.id = af.additionalfieldid
                                    WHERE      aff.fieldname = 'ApplicantDogRestricted'
                                    AND        af.linkid = owner.id) AS applicantdogrestricted,
                         (
                                    SELECT     af.value
                                    FROM       additional af
                                    INNER JOIN additionalfield aff
                                    ON         aff.id = af.additionalfieldid
                                    WHERE      aff.fieldname = 'ApplicantDogHighEnergy'
                                    AND        af.linkid = owner.id) AS applicantdoghighenergy,
                         (
                                    SELECT     af.value
                                    FROM       additional af
                                    INNER JOIN additionalfield aff
                                    ON         aff.id = af.additionalfieldid
                                    WHERE      aff.fieldname = 'ApplicantDogPuppy'
                                    AND        af.linkid = owner.id) AS applicantdogpuppy,
                         (
                                    SELECT     af.value
                                    FROM       additional af
                                    INNER JOIN additionalfield aff
                                    ON         aff.id = af.additionalfieldid
                                    WHERE      aff.fieldname = 'ApplicantWeightRestriction'
                                    AND        af.linkid = owner.id) AS applicantweightrestriction,
                         createdby
                FROM     owner
                WHERE    matchactive = '1'
                AND      matchspecies = '1'
                AND      idcheck = '1'
                AND      additionalflags NOT LIKE '%Fosterer-Dog%'
                ORDER BY o.matchadded DESC
```

I am expecting the query to result in a report that lists applicants by the day they applied -in descending order. There is data in between, but the last column should be a list of dogs that meet their search request.

Comment: What is `o` (from, among other, `o.matchadded`)? You don't select from a table `o` or have a table or an alias or a sub-query named `o`. Same with `a` and `s`.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the alias of owner. Add `o` after owner and for other tables too like `a, s` etc. to alias it.

Aliasing allows you to distinguish names of the tables when using a table/columns multiple times in the same query mainly.